# How does one programmatically access email account settings of mail app in Mavericks?

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-mavericks

I would like to access email account settings, such as username, password, port, ssl settings etc that are stored by the stock OSX Mail app, from my app. Where are these settings stored, and how does one read them ?

Comment: I just hope that any third party app is not able to do this. This could a serious privacy issue.

Comment: No way to access the password in the keychain without the user authenticating first ... luckily. For the rest, that isn't too hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passwords are usually stored in the keychain, if the user enabled storage of passwords. The other parameters are in the preference file.

Before accessing them make sure the user gives its okay.

Comment: where would you find the preference file ?

Comment: it gets stored for each user in the Preferences folder. Don't know if nowadays with sandboxing it is still accessible.

Comment: I don't see it . There is com.apple.mail-shared.plist in /Users/username/Library/preferences . But that doesn't contain port settings, or account names.

Comment: I am on 10.7 there it exists, but probably not so easy to find on 10.8/10.9